# Why am I getting 'Unable to create process' error while running conda commands

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, windows-11

I installed anaconda following all the steps and also added path in environment variables but whenever i use any conda command in the terminal it shows this error.

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\<USER NAME>\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\<USER NAME>\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" '
```

I tried reinstalling anaconda but it is showing same error.

Comment: can u give the information about your computer?